# unable to add external jsx file

Tags: reactjs

I'm using babel-standalone and am trying to add external file for react jsx code.  I use npm install http-server -g and have that working.  I place both my html and js file in the server public directory.  When I try to load with the following:

```
 <script src ='react001.jsx' type='text/jsx'></script>
```

the file doesn't load.  When I load with:

```
<script src ='react001.jsx' ></script>
```

the file loads but I get unexpected token error in the console.

Here are the two files:

react001.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>


  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/create-react-class@15.6.2/create-react-class.js"></script>
  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


  <title>React Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'></div>

<script type='text/jsx' src='react001.jsx' ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the jsx file:

```
class HelloUser extends React.Component {
        render() {
           return (
              <div>
                 <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}!</h1>
                 <h1>Hello</h1>
              </div>
           );
        }
     }



     ReactDOM.render(
              <HelloUser name='Blobby2' />,
              document.getElementById('container')
     )
```

Comment: sooo... it sounds like the 2nd thing is right, and you just have an error in the file?  Put up the file and the error text and maybe we can see something?

Comment: @DCR have you solved this? I tested your code and it runs fine for me.

Comment: yes, I was having a problem with http-server but I fixed that and all is well